# Stripe Ruby On Rails Server login_link responseSerializationFailed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, stripe-payments

I have a functioning Ruby on Rails server which is being used to handle Stripe account creation, payments, and express (connect) account management. The api says the the login_links.create api should return a JSON, however I receive the error:

"responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
"

when trying to receive any response from my own api client. The API for login_links (https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_login_link) is somewhat vague, but I am a ROR beginner so any help is appreciated.

My ROR Server /CreateBalanceLink function:

```
post '/createBalanceLink' do        
    begin
        accountID = params[:account]
        account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(accountID)
        account.login_links.create
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    status 402
    return "Error creating link: #{e.message}"

end

status 200
    return "Link successfully created"
end
```

My API Client:

```
func generateBalanceAccessLink(stripeAccount: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> ()) {
let url = "https://******.herokuapp.com/createBalanceLink" //Replaced for security
let params: [String: Any] = [
    "account": stripeAccount
    ]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON { responseJSON in
        switch responseJSON.result {
        case .success(let json):
            let data:[String:AnyObject] = json as! [String : AnyObject]
            print(data)
            //print("Created Link:",data["url"] as! String)
            //appDelegate.balanceLink = data["url"] as! String
            completion(true)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your Ruby on Rails server does not respond with **JSON format**, the response seems to be **plain text**.

And then your API client throws an error when it tries to parse the answer because what it gets is not valid JSON format, it's plain text.

So I think you should update the Ruby on Rails server so that it returns JSON, whether there is an error or not.

For example, say you have a `create_link` route, you could do something like this, inside your Ruby on Rails controller:

```
def create_link
  begin
    accountID = params[:account]
    account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(accountID)
    account.login_links.create
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    return render status: 402, json: {message: "Error creating link: #{e.message}"}
  end
  render status: 200, json: {message: "Link successfully created"}
end
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help- I called this def and unfortunately now receive a "FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(500))". For some reason it seems like the create login link call is failing

Comment: Obviously there is something wrong with your Ruby on Rails server that responds with a error code 500.
Did you put the code sample I checked in a Ruby on Rail controller and did you create the route?
Could you try to test the Ruby on Rails server separately (not from your API client that uses Alamofire)?
For example you could use a tool like Postman to send a POST request to `https://******.herokuapp.com/createBalanceLink` with the right `account` parameter and then the error message would be easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to call create so instead of

```
account.login_links.create
```

you want

```
account.login_links.create()
```

Comment: Creating the call like that produces the same error